# How can you make a passive sentence with only a do-auxiliary?

Tags: american-english

We usually use the verb *be* when we want to form passive voice sentences. But I am curious as to whether we can form the passive voice with only the auxiliary verb *do*.

Comment: Could you add some examples to your question?

Comment: @user : If I could have made it, Why I asked you?

Comment: Perhaps User was asking because they thought you might have some ideas  but weren't sure?

Comment: Only with ellipsis of the verb-to-be:  <asked while peeking in the oven at a cake> Done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pullum lists a number of verbs besides the passive auxiliary itself](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922) including ***come, get, go, have, hear, make, need,*** and ***see***, but he doesn't list ***do*** specifically and I can't think of a ***do***-passive construction myself.

As far as I'm aware, the answer is no, you generally cannot form a passive with ***do*** alone.

Comment: Well, there's the emphatic infinitive: *do be guided by your conscience* ... Would that count?

Comment: @Araucaria The OP said "**only** the auxiliary verb *do*".  Your example has  *be* as well, so I don't think it counts.

Comment: Ah, yes, true :)

Comment: @snailBoat: I have got a question, Who do you edit if to whether? Also if I want to use the if instead whether, is still good?. Also, I want to know if you yes at above question, What does they have difference between them?

Comment: @user1917217 Following *as to*, the usual choice is *whether*. In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=34402677), we find 2438 results for *as to whether* but only 8 for *as to if*.  If you'd like to know more about *if* and *whether*, please ask a new question.